# Windows 10 fails to register host to DNS server on boot

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internal-dns, dhcp-server, dns-server

So the situation is as follows.

We have rolled out Windows 10 laptops that auto-connect to the wireless. 
The clients are Windows 10 and the DNS and DHCP server are Windows. 
When they are docked, they detect the wired connection and disable wifi.

So far so good..

The problem:

We boot a laptop that has a wired connection, the machine will receive 2 IP addresses. 1 wired, 1 wireless.

*> At this moment the DNS record on the DNS server has the Wifi address listed.*

Windows will auto-deactivate the wireless connection and only the wired connection is listed as active.

*> At this moment the DNS record on the DNS server **still** has the Wifi address listed. So there is no longer a way to connect to the machine through their hostname.*

When I check eventlogs I get:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client
Date:          25/05/2020 16:03:13
Event ID:      8018
Task Category: (1028)
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          NETWORK SERVICE
Computer:      .............
Description:
The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings: ....

The reason the system could not register these RRs was because the DNS server contacted refused the update request. The reasons for this might be (a) you are not allowed to update the specified DNS domain name, or (b) because the DNS server authoritative for this name does not support the DNS dynamic update protocol.

To register the DNS host (A or AAAA) resource records using the specific DNS domain name and IP addresses for this adapter, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator.
```

When I unplug the UTP cable and plug it back in, it registers fine and updates the DNS server. So I don't understand why it would not work on boot.

**I have found a solution that works, but is not the most secure:**

When I go to our DNS server and I set Dynamic Updates to accept "Nonsecure and secure" and reboot the laptop, everything works without problem.

[image: Screenshot of Dynamic Updates option on DNS server]

But since this is a major security risk I have set it back to "Secure only".

**In short**: For an unknown reason (and only at system startup) the wired IP is seen as insecure and the DNS server will not accept the request to register.